# Finding HTMLattribute using Id or Class Name

Tags: c#, html, attributes

I have this html code

button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" id="btnBuildAllSubmit" disabled="disabled">Support

I am currently using FindElement, but I cant get the attribute. 
I want to search the page and make sure that the disabled attribute is displayed. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Selenium WebDriver to run what appear to be your tests?

Comment: Yes I am using Selenium WebDriver to run the tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this should work:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnBuildAllSubmit"));
string disabledAttributeValue = element.GetAttribute("disabled");

if(disabledAttributeValue == null)
{
    // The disabled attribute is not present
}
```

Per the code:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebElement.cs#L367

If the attribute is just `<h1 disabled></h1>`, the driver will return `disabled` as the value, otherwise, it will return `null` if it does not exist, or the value for `disabled` if there is a value set.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use XPath Navigation ?

```
    // create an XPathDocument object
    XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(yourStreamInstance);
    // create a navigator for the xpath doc
    XPathNavigator xNav = xmlPathDoc.CreateNavigator();
    //run the XPath query
    XPathNodeIterator xPathIt = p_xPathNav.Select("//button[@disabled]");

    //use the XPathNodeIterator to display the results
        if (xPathIt.Count > 0) 
        {
            xPathIt.MoveNext();
            Console.WriteLine(xPathIt.Current.Value);
        } 
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No disabled attribute");
        }
```